# How can I create two separate pygame displays? If I can't, how could I create two instances of pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I want to create two separate `pygame` displays. I know that it's impossible to do that with a single instance of pygame. I was wondering how/if I could implement any of the following solutions:

1. Create a separate module to run the function that uses the separate display. Will this use a separate instance of pygame from my main code and therefore be able to run?
2. Run the script from within itself with some special parameters using a subshell, parse `sys.argv`, and then run the function in the second instance. How would I ensure cross-platform compatibility?
3. Something else?

I don't care about how inefficient, ugly, etc. the program is as a result.  I simply want to make this work.

Importantly, the main code must communicate with the relevant code (i.e. change some variables belonging to `extraDisplayManager` below) but I plan to use pickle to save to a file and communicate that way. I'm already multi-threading the relevant part though, so a lack of synchronicity doesn't matter.

My code is fairly long and complicated, so I won't post it here, but the gist of the relevant part is:

```py
def mainCode(*someargs):
    d = pygame.display.set_mode(dimensions)
    if relevantArg:
        extraDisplayManager = RelevantClass(*someotherargs)
        threading.Thread(target=extraDisplayManager.relevantFunction,
                         daemon=True).start()


...

class RelevantClass:
    def relevantFunction(self, *someotherargs):
        self.d = pygame.display.set_mode(dimensions)
        while True:
            updateDisplay(someargs) # This is part of my main code, but it
            # is standalone, so I could copy it to a new module
```

I'd appreciate if you could answer some of my questions or show me some relevant documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really (*really*) need two displays, you can use python's [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html) module to spawn a process and use a [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) to pass data between the two processes.

Here's an example I hacked together:

```
import pygame
import pygame.freetype
import random
import multiprocessing as mp

# a simple class that renders a button
# if you press it, it calls a callback function
class Button(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, callback, *grps):
        super().__init__(*grps)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((200, 200))
        self.image.set_colorkey((1,2,3))
        self.image.fill((1,2,3))
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, pygame.Color('red'), (100, 100), 50)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(300, 240))
        self.callback = callback

    def update(self, events, dt):
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if (pygame.Vector2(e.pos) - pygame.Vector2(self.rect.center)).length() <= 50:
                    pygame.draw.circle(self.image, pygame.Color('darkred'), (100, 100), 50)
                    self.callback()
            if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                    pygame.draw.circle(self.image, pygame.Color('red'), (100, 100), 50)

# a simple class that display a text for 1 second anywhere
class Message(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, screen_rect, text, font, *grps):
        super().__init__(*grps)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((300, 100))
        self.image.set_colorkey((1,2,3))
        self.image.fill((1,2,3))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(random.randint(0, screen_rect.width), 
                                                random.randint(0, screen_rect.height)))
        font.render_to(self.image, (5, 5), text)
        self.timeout = 1000
        self.rect.clamp_ip(screen_rect)

    def update(self, events, dt):
        if self.timeout > 0:
            self.timeout = max(self.timeout - dt, 0)
        else:
            self.kill()

# Since we start multiple processes, let's create a mainloop function
# that can be used by all processes. We pass a logic_init_func-function
# that can do some initialisation and returns a callback function itself.
# That callback function is called before all the events are handled.
def mainloop(logic_init_func, q):
    import pygame
    import pygame.freetype
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 480))
    screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    dt = 0
    sprites_grp = pygame.sprite.Group()

    callback = logic_init_func(screen, sprites_grp, q)

    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        callback(events)

        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

        sprites_grp.update(events, dt)
        screen.fill((80, 80, 80))
        sprites_grp.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
        dt = clock.tick(60)

# The main game function is returned by this function.
# We need a reference to the slave process so we can terminate it when
# we want to exit the game.
def game(slave):
    def game_func(screen, sprites_grp, q):

        # This initializes the game.
        # A bunch of words, and one of it is randomly choosen to be
        # put into the queue once the button is pressed
        words = ('Ouch!', 'Hey!', 'NOT AGAIN!', 'that hurts...', 'STOP IT')

        def trigger():
            q.put_nowait(random.choice(words))

        Button(trigger, sprites_grp)

        def callback(events):
            # in the mainloop, we check for the QUIT event
            # and kill the slave process if we want to exit
            for e in events:
                if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    slave.terminate()
                    slave.join()

        return callback

    return game_func

def second_display(screen, sprites_grp, q):

    # we create font before the mainloop
    font = pygame.freetype.SysFont(None, 48)

    def callback(events):
        try:
            # if there's a message in the queue, we display it
            word = q.get_nowait()
            Message(screen.get_rect(), word, font, sprites_grp)
        except:
            pass

    return callback

def main():
    # we use the spawn method to create the other process
    # so it will use the same method on each OS.
    # Otherwise, fork will be used on Linux instead of spawn
    mp.set_start_method('spawn')
    q = mp.Queue()

    slave = mp.Process(target=mainloop, args=(second_display, q))
    slave.start()

    mainloop(game(slave), q)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Of course this is only a simple example; you probably want more error handling, stop nesting functions like crazy, etc etc. Also, there are also other ways to do [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) in python.

Last, but not least, think about if you *really* need two pygame displays, because multiprocessing adds a ton of complexity. I answered some pygame questions on SO already and almost always the OP was asking an XY question when asking about threading/multiprocessing with pygame.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and links to documentation! Although it does appear quite complicated to use `multiprocessing`, and I'm sure there are better ways of doing it (e.g. having both "windows" side by side in one display), the length of my current code warrants a plug-and-play solution, which you have provided.