# How do I get PyGame processes to communicate with eachother?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pygame, multiprocessing

I have a program that uses multiple PyGame processes, ran using `multiprocessing`:

```py
# ./__init__.py
import pygame
import window_one
import window_two
import window_three

pygame.init()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window_one_proc = Process(target=window_one_proc.win_one).start()
    window_two_proc = Process(target=window_two_proc.win_two).start()
    window_three_proc = Process(target=window_three_proc.win_three).start()

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # send events to those windows
```

```py
# ./window_one.py (the other windows are similar)
import pygame

def win_one() -> None:
    # ...pygame window setup...

    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
        
        window.fill((0, 0, 0))
        bracket = arial_font.render("[", True, (255, 255, 255))
        window.blit(bracket, (0, -35))

        pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.quit()
```

I'm trying to have `__init__.py` send the PyGame events to the other processes, so that `window_one.py` and all the windows like it can react to PyGame events that get sent from the `__init__.py` process.

I first tried using the `socket` library but I kept getting `OSError`'s no matter what port or IP I tried to use in `__init__py`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 122, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 131, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 246, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 297, in _fixup_main_from_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 286, in run_path
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 98, in _run_module_code
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "c:\Users\Marcus\Repos\WindowPong\windowpong\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    event_socket.bind(('127.0.0.5', 5439))
OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
```

I couldn't figure out what was causing that OSError so I looked around and found an existing thread called [Interprocess communication in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920858/interprocess-communication-in-python), which seemed to have the perfect solution. Unfortunately, it also errored, this time with a `ConnectionRefusedError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Marcus\Repos\WindowPong\windowpong\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    conn = Client(address, authkey=b'secret password')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 518, in Client
    c = SocketClient(address)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 646, in SocketClient
    s.connect(address)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

By this point I had already spent over a week trying to figure this out, and I still don't have it working, so I gave up and am just asking for help here. I'm just starting to experiment with multiple processes and I cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: It's clear what to me what you actually want to do. First of all, your `__init__` won't have many events to send because there's no window. You also didn't include the code that does your the actual communication stuff. Your problems are not directly pygame related, nonetheless, here are two examples, one with [UDP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361973/post-event-pygame/11362449#11362449) and one with [`multiprocessing`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56334330/how-can-i-create-two-separate-pygame-displays-if-i-cant-how-could-i-create-tw/56336241#56336241)